# Manipulating column names in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I converted the following dictionary to a dataframe:

```
dic = {'US':{'Traffic':{'new':1415, 'repeat':670}, 'Sales':{'new':67068, 'repeat':105677}},
      'UK': {'Traffic':{'new':230, 'repeat':156}, 'Sales':{'new':4568, 'repeat':10738}}}
d1 = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in dic.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            d1[(k, k2)].update({k1: v2})


df.insert(loc=2, column=' ', value=None)
df.insert(loc=0, column='Mode', value='Website')
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Metric", level=1)
```

The dataframe currently looks like:[image: current dataframe]

**How do I move the column header - Mode to the following row?**

To get an output of this sort:[image: required dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```py
df.insert(loc=0, column='Mode', value='Website')
```

to this:

```py
df.insert(loc=0, column=('', 'Mode'), value='Website')
```

then your full code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

dic = {'US':{'Traffic':{'new':1415, 'repeat':670}, 'Sales':{'new':67068, 'repeat':105677}},
      'UK': {'Traffic':{'new':230, 'repeat':156}, 'Sales':{'new':4568, 'repeat':10738}}}
d1 = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in dic.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            d1[(k, k2)].update({k1: v2})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1)
df.insert(loc=0, column=('', 'Mode'), value='Website')
```

and this is your `df`

[image]

Rinse and repeat with your empty column between US and UK.

(though, admittedly, this looks like a strange way of handling stuff)